# Translating a particular statement into quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have the generalized statement: 
$$\text{It is } \textbf{not}\text{ necessarily the case that }P(x,y).$$
The translation appropriate is, for me, hard to come by. I have attempted this:
$$\forall x\exists y\left[\neg P(x,y)\right]$$

I am nonetheless led to believe that I am wrong; what is the proper way of translating this statement?

(Original: [deleted because the wrong wording was put](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132763/translating-a-particular-statement-into-quantifiers))

Comment: It typically means that $P(x,y)$ may be either true or false. You may not assume the truth or falsehood of $P(x,y)$ as a general statement.

Comment: Again, what you have is "everything has something it's not related to.", but this time what you want is more "not all things are related", or equivalently "there is a pair of somethings that are not related"

Comment: @MPW not if this is a lead up to modal logic, where "not necessarily" means "possibly not", and "possible" means there is at least one case (or world) where it can happen.

Comment: In that case, perhaps $\exists x\exists y [\neg P(x,y)]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "not necessarily".

Some will say "not necessarily" means "may or may not be the case".  In other words, the truth is indefinite.

$$\forall x\forall y :(P(x,y)\vee \neg P(x,y))$$

However, that is not a very useful statement.

Then there is the interpretation that if something is "not necessary" then it is "possibly not", which means "there is a way it can not happen".

$$\exists x \exists y : \neg P(x,y)$$

---

If you're using modal logic, we might say: $\neg \Box \, P(x,y)$ or equivalently. $\Diamond \neg P(x,y)$

Comment: The latter statement ($\exists x\exists y:\neg P(x,y)$) works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about
$ \exists x, y  [\neg P(x, y)] $ ?

This means that there are values of x and y for which P might not hold, which is another way to word what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) and can be written as $\neg\square p(x,y)$.